# Row-wise sum for select columns while ignoring NAs

Tags: r, sum

I want to create a new column that has the sum (row-wise) for select columns in a dataframe. I'd like to ignore NAs for the sum (if any) and reference the columns by their names.

Can anyone help me with this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  In the future please provide some code a minimum working example and what you have tried so far.  The answer to this question should have been easy to google.  However as you are new, you are entitled some grace.  Please see my answer below.

Comment: To close voters: How is this question no MCVE? It might be "unclear" or "too broad", but this question is not a debugging question. **Only** debugging questions require a [MCVE] (MCVE). "No MCVE" is **only valid** for debugging questions. All other question types do not *require* code. Having code can greatly improve them, often making the difference between them being on-topic and being "unclear" or "too broad", but code is not *required*.  [Homework questions require an attempt, but that's unclear/too broad/custom.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to accomplish this:

```
#make a data frame
df <- data.frame(a = c(1,2,3),
                 b = c(1,NA,3),
                 c = c(1,2,3))

#use rowSums on a dataframe made with each of your columns and specify na.rm = TRUE
df$mySum <- rowSums(cbind(df$a,df$b), na.rm = TRUE)
```